# Expo eas cli build QR code won't open the app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, eas

I'm fairly new to the Expo cli. And I have an app that I'm trying to develop. I am using 'react-native-google-mobile-ads' module in my application. In order to use this module, I logged in with the eas cli and got a build. The application is currently running smoothly in the simulator with the 'expo run:ios' command, but it does not work when I try to open the qr code it generates from a phone and tablet (Expo Go is installed and I ran the commands 'eas device:create' , 'eas build --profile preview --platform all' and downloaded the profile from the web and installed it on the devices.) Please help me. I leave my expo information below.

```
expo: ~48.0.18 => 48.0.19 
      react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
      react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
      react-native: 0.71.8 => 0.71.8 
      react-native-web: ~0.18.10 => 0.18.12 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      eas-cli: 3.13.3
      expo-cli: 6.3.8
```